# SVG paths are not scaling to fit the viewport

Tags: svg

I have an svg with  a viewport, the svg is rendered 100% width.

All of the path points are within the width and height set in the viewport but they don't scale to fit and are cut off at the bottom.

Is their something else that has to be done to make the paths scale with the viewport?

```
<svg id="chart" viewport="0 0 960 900" width="100%">
<path id="meanp2" fill="#00ba41" d="M0,394.651913982198L89,381.74828040247746L178,365.8363447921115L267,346.2147635294238L356,322.01868451830455L445,292.181627470022L534,255.38847710490052L623,210.01751737519893L712,154.06895177627143L801,85.07675916615301L890,0L890,450L801,450L712,450L623,450L534,450L445,450L356,450L267,450L178,450L89,450L0,450Z"></path>
<path id="meanp1" fill="#ffffff" opacity="0.5" d="M0,394.651913982198L89,385.9386669043237L178,375.8537251554601L267,364.18114785230546L356,350.6709993268097L445,335.03399745134334L534,316.93531946923986L623,295.98743269985823L712,271.7417966077222L801,243.67925855870456L890,211.19893761517645L890,450L801,450L712,450L623,450L534,450L445,450L356,450L267,450L178,450L89,450L0,450Z"></path>
<path fill="#00ba41" id="meanm1" d="M0,394.651913982198L89,394.4918599690828L178,394.3313431163474L267,394.1703620855654L356,394.0089155344399L445,393.8470021167925L534,393.684620482552L623,393.52176927774303L712,393.35844714447484L801,393.19465272092987L890,393.0303846413527L890,450L801,450L712,450L623,450L534,450L445,450L356,450L267,450L178,450L89,450L0,450Z"></path>
<path id="meanm2" fill="#ffffff" d="M0,394.651913982198L89,398.867056781845L178,402.7611870569451L267,406.35875215028454L356,409.6823375689777L445,412.7528087762397L534,415.58944218472675L623,418.21004617381925L712,420.63107289059565L801,422.8677215363817L890,424.9340337873086L890,450L801,450L712,450L623,450L534,450L445,450L356,450L267,450L178,450L89,450L0,450Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: viewBox, not viewport

Comment: Seems more of a typo question to me.

Answer (score -1):

it's viewBox not viewport which is relate to the window.